# Format a string of names like 'Bart, Lisa & Maggie'

Tags: javascript

After doing freecodecamp javascript i thought i try codewars javascript fundamentals.
well fail on 1st one. i know solutions out there but i wanted you to see what my idea for it was.

Kind regards

```
function list(names){
  //your code here
  if (names.length >=1) {
    
    let entry = names.shift();
    console.log(entry.name+", ")
  }
  if(names.length <=1){
    console.log(" &"+names.name)
  }
}
```

Given: an array containing hashes of names

Return: a string formatted as a list of names separated by commas except for the last two names, which should be separated by an ampersand.

Example:

```
list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ])
// returns 'Bart, Lisa & Maggie'

list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'} ])
// returns 'Bart & Lisa'

list([ {name: 'Bart'} ])
// returns 'Bart'

list([])
// returns ''
```

Note: all the hashes are pre-validated and will only contain A-Z, a-z, '-' and '.'.

Comment: do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```js
console.log( list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ]) )

console.log( list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'} ]) )

console.log( list([ {name: 'Bart'} ]) )

console.log( list([]) )

function list(arr){
  let len = arr.length;
  if(len==0) return '';
  return arr.slice(0, len-1).map(p=>p.name).join(", ") + (len>1 ? ' & ' : '') + arr[len-1].name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You version will not produce the expected result.

```
function list(names){
 if (names.length > 1) {
   return `${otherNames(names)} & ${names[names.length - 1].name}`
 } else if (names.length === 1) {
   return names[0].name
 }
  return '';
}

function otherNames(array) {
  return array.splice(0, array.length - 1).map(person => person.name).join(', ');
}
```

This should do.

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of thing, it can be useful to break the task down into separate functions, and then combine them as needed. Here the function `prop` is used to get the property `name`, and the function `list` is used to generate the string from an array of names. The two are combined in `listByName`, using `map` to get the name from each object in the input array.

```js
const list = arr => arr.slice(0,-1).join(", ") + (arr.length>1 ? " & " : "") + arr.slice(-1);
const prop = propName => x => x[propName];
const listByName = arr => list(arr.map(prop('name')))

console.log(listByName([{ name: "Bart" }, { name: "Lisa" }, { name: "Maggie" }]));
console.log(listByName([{ name: "Bart" }, { name: "Lisa" }]));
console.log(listByName([{ name: "Bart" }]));
console.log(listByName([]));
```

Depending on the use case, you might want to add error checking code for cases where invalid input is used: for example, objects without a name property, or non objects in an array, or input taht isn't an array being passed to `listByName`.